# Vue 2, Cannot reference Prop Object in template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Problem: Although from the Vue DevTools I am passing the prop correctly and the router-view component has access to the data that it needs and in the correct format, whenever I try to access any of the data properties from within the template I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`. It's really confusing because from the DevTools everything is a valid object and the properties are not null.

*App.js*

```js
const game = new Vue({
    el: '#game',

    data: function() {
        return {
            meta: null,
            empire: null,
            planets: null
        };
    },

    created: () => {
        axios.get('/api/game').then(function (response) {
            game.meta = response.data.meta;
            game.empire = response.data.empire;
            game.planets = response.data.planets;
        });
    },

    router // router is in separate file but nothing special
});
```

*main.blade.php*

```
<router-view :meta="meta" :empire="empire" :planets="planets"></router-view>
```

*script section of my Component.vue file*

```js
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {

    }
  },

  props: {
    meta: {
      type: Object
    },
    empire: {
      type: Object
    },
    planets: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/QbYfB - Image of my Vue Dev Tools with router component selected.

Answer (score 0):

[router-view](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html) is a component from [view-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) which can help render [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-views.html). You can not pass empire and planets to it as those are props of your component.

You have to have following kind of code to pass empire and planets to your component:

```
<my-component :meta="meta" :empire="empire" :planets="planets"></my-component>
```

You can see more details around this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props).

Comment: I'm using .vue files with a <template> tag. I never reference the component via <my-component>. Should I add the v-binds to the <template> element?

Comment: @TimTheEnchant3r I am not sure of your use case, You can see an example [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/ItemList.vue#L14), where [item](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/Item.vue) is a component.

Comment: You can still pass prop to `router-view`

Answer (score 0):

Because of your data is async loading so when `my Component.vue` renders your data in parent component may not be there. So you need to check if your data is loaded. You can try this code:

```
{{ meta != null && meta.name }}
```

PS: Your `created` hook should be:

```
 created() {
    axios.get('/api/game').then((response) => {
        this.game.meta = response.data.meta;
        this.game.empire = response.data.empire;
        this.game.planets = response.data.planets;
    });
},
```